# how to add foreign key binding source

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am just getting started in C# and want to create a simple DB app that allows me to create a customer entry (table `Customer`) and then create records for that customers children (similar to table `Orders`).

I have installed VS2012 express and SQL2012 express.

1. I first created a table in DB called `customer` and can now display this and add/delete from it.
2. I then created a table called `children`, made a foreign key in it - the `custid` from the `customer` table.
3. I added this (`children`) table to my solution and when editing the `dataSource` with the designer I can see there is a realtionship between the 2 tables `KF-Children-customers`.
4. Finally I added a `DataGridView` to my solution, clicked the [smart-tag] button and wanted to select the foreign key *relationship* but it was *not visible*.

**Q:** Do I need to do something since I added the `children` table and foreign keys etc after I had already added the `customer` table to the solution?

I really am just getting started with C# and .Net, I have done no previous programming so please take pity on me if I have not fully explained things!

Craig

Answer (score 0):

Your Question isn't very clear. Customers is DB or Table ? In case if you have two different tables in a database with foreign key constraints, you may need to use "JOIN" specifically inner join may help you.

SQL JOINS are explained easy here : http://www.lsql-tutorial.ru

sample query: "SELECT userlist.username,tblcountry.country from userlist 
                inner join  tblcountry on tblcountry.countryID=userlist.countryname";

Tables: userlist, tblcountry.
both the tables are liked with foreign constraints.

Comment: Customers and children are both tables in the same DB.  I am trying to access them in a VS2012 c#/Winforms application using databinding.

Comment: In customers have a identity column and make it Primary key, in Children have a identity column and create a Foreign key. code for databind:

Comment: Yeah, that all works fine. It's in visual Studio, when adding the datagrid view that the foreign key relationship is not showing as one of the options to pick. I have started a blank document and added a new datasource to the same database and this time when I add the datagrid I can select FkChildrenCustomersBindingSource - so I assume from the DB side of things all is good. It's just that in the other project I must need to refresh something to make it 'see' the relationship between the customers and the children?

Answer (score 0):

In customers have a identity column and make it Primary key, in Children have a identity column and create a Foreign key. 
code for databind:

void gridbind()
 {
   try
    {
     string qrystring = "your query";

```
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qrystring, conn);
             SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(qrystring, conn);
             SqlCommandBuilder scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(DA);
             DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
             DA.Fill(dTable);
             GridView1.DataSource = dTable;
             GridView1.DataBind();

}
         catch (SqlException)
         {
             lblnameinfo.Text = "Gridview binding error";
         }
         finally
         {
             if (conn != null)
             {
                 conn.Close();
             }
         }
     }
```

*you need joins if you refer data from one table to another like Foreign constrains. 
* This is a sample code..may help you..